# errors in java when trying to call objects, setters getters and constructors

Tags: java

When I try to call an object from a different class , make setters and getters and make constructors in java eclispe keeps coming up with errors saying this "Duplicate local variable MyClassTWOObject
    Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody

```
at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:180)"


enter code h    /*Calling object from MYClassTWO EXAMPLE
     *Calling object from MYClassTWO EXAMPLE 
     */

MyClassTWO  MyClassTWOObject = **new MyClassTWO();**
MyClassTWOObject.Chicken();
System.out.println();
System.out.println();

   /*EXAMPLE of return statement
    *EXAMPLE of return statement
    */

int x =  returnSeventySeven();    
System.out.print(x);
System.out.println();


int result = square(3);
System.out.println();
System.out.println(result);
System.out.println();

  /*Getters & Setters EXAMPLE 
   *Getters & Setters EXAPLE 
   */
 MyClassTWO obj1 = **new MyClassTWO();**

 obj1.setX(25);
System.out.print(obj1.getX());



MyClassTWO **MyClassTWOObject** = new MyClassTWO("Dog");
MyClassTWOObject.neck()**;**ere
```

All the code that has been flagged up as wrong by eclipse is in bold

Comment: All code that is flagged up as wrong in eclispe is surrounded by two asterisks

Comment: Where is the structure of the class `MyClassTWO`? And how the code for this class is written, from where you planning to call the method/s of `MyClassTWO` class? In simple terms, where is the class declaration and method body, from where you writing above lines?

Answer (score 0):

This line here is the problem:

MyClassTWO **MyClassTWOObject** = new MyClassTWO("Dog");

You are creating and assigning a second object with the same name, you either need to give it a different name, or if you wish to just change the object which the variable points to, you can just put:

MyClassTWOObject = new MyClassTWO("Dog");

Note that the convention for variables in java is to use camelCase starting with a lower case letter.

Comment: I added a 2 onto the end of "MyClassTWOObject" to make it different and it fixed that issue but the other errors still remain which I have surrounded with double asterisks

Comment: I'm unsure as to what the current error is. Could you clarify and I will amend my answer?

Comment: The program still contains errors which have ** surrounding them in the grey box below the question     the errors I am referring to are MyClassTWO  MyClassTWOObject = **new MyClassTWO();**,                           MyClassTWO obj1 = **new MyClassTWO();**,       and                                         MyClassTWOObject.neck()**;*